# Distributing System.Net.Http

Tags: c#, nuget, httpclient

So I have recently started working with calling REST APIs from C#. From my research it seems that the best way to do it is to use HttpClient which is part of System.Net.Http.

I learned that to get this library I have to download and install it from NuGet since it isn't part of .NET 4.5 by default.

I'm guessing this means I have to get all the needed assemblies for HttpClient (it looks like there is 4 of them) and manually distribute them with any project that is going to use HttpClient.

It just seems strange that I'd have to do that with what seems like standard .NET assemblies from Microsoft.

Comment: There is nothing unusual about libraries having dependencies.

Comment: "In recent years, the team has been using NuGet as a .NET Framework release vehicle, to release features and fixes available more quickly" https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/p/nugetpackages/
My take on it is they are doing it for any package that's not really needed for every application. Which this easily fits for any self contained desktop apps.

Comment: @WilliamXifaras Yes, I realize that. I just seemed odd to me for that to be the case with libraries that seem like they would be part of the standard .NET installation.

Answer (score 2):

`HttpClient` comes with .NET 4.5 and above (see Version Information [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.110))). It's also available on NuGet for [older platforms](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Net.Http) and for [.NET Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Net.Http) (this is the latest version, and is also compatible with most .NET implementations as it conforms to .NET Standard 1.1).

If you're using .NET 4.5, just add a reference to it - you do not need the package (References > Add > Assemblies > Framework > `System.Net.Http`).

Comment: After I read about HttpClient adding System.Net.Http it to my .NET 4.5 project was the first thing I tried but it wasn't there. If it had been I wouldn't have even bothered using NuGet to add it. Would HttpClient even work with a .NET version prior to 4.5? HttpClient uses Tasks. The methods (GET,PUT,POST,DELETE) all return Tasks and are "awaitable". Aren't await and async features of .NET 4.5?

Comment: Yes, Tasks were added in .NET 4 and await/async was added in .NET 4.5. From what I can tell the GET, PUT, POST and DELETE methods in HttpClient are all "awaitable" meaning it requires .NET 4.5. I triple checked the target framework. It is absolutely .NET 4.5.